# Reversals of autonomous subsets in right-angled Coxeter groups

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, coxeter-groups

This question has to do with some experimental phenomenon in groups generated by involutions that I cannot explain.

Let $G$ be a finite, undirected graph, and let $W$ be the corresponding *right-angled Coxeter group*, i.e., the generators of $W$ are the vertices $v \in G$, and we have relations $v^2=1$ for all $v$ and $wv=vw$ if $v$ and $w$ are **non-adjacent** in $G$.

Recall that a *Coxeter element* $c$ in $W$ is a product of the generators $v$ in some order. It is well-known that Coxeter elements in such a right-angled Coxeter group correspond to acyclic orientations of $G$: for an acyclic orientation $\mathcal{O}$ of $G$, the corresponding Coxeter element $c$ is $c_{\mathcal{O}} = v_1v_2\cdots v_n$ where if $(v_i,v_j)$ is an arc of $\mathcal{O}$ then $i < j$. (This is enough to specify the Coxeter element because we can commute non-adjacent vertices.)

Furthermore, two Coxeter elements $c_{\mathcal{O}}$ and $c_{\mathcal{O}'}$ are conjugate in $W$ iff $\mathcal{O}'$ can be obtained from $\mathcal{O}$ by a series of *sink-source reversals*: choose a sink in $\mathcal{O}$ and reverse the direction of all arcs incident to that sink so that it becomes a source. In fact, there is even an explicit numerical criterion for deciding if $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{O}'$ are related by a series of sink-source reversals, having to do with choosing a basis of the space of cycles of $G$ (see Pretzel, "On reorienting graphs by pushing down maximal vertices", https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00390104).

My question is about a different kind of reversal, corresponding to something different than conjugacy in $W$.

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an acyclic orientation of $G$; we say that a subset $A$ of vertices of $G$ is *autonomous* with respect to $\mathcal{O}$ if all vertices in $A$ have the same relationship to any vertex outside of $A$, i.e., for $a, a' \in A$ and $x \notin A$: we have an arc $(a,x)$ in $\mathcal{O}$ iff we have an arc $(a',x)$ in $\mathcal{O}$; we have an arc $(x,a)$ in $\mathcal{O}$ iff we have an arc $(x,a')$ in $\mathcal{O}$; and $a$ and $x$ are non-adjacent in $G$ iff $a'$ and $x$ are non-adjacent in $G$. For such an autonomous subset, let $\mathcal{O}_{-A}$ denote the orientation obtained from $\mathcal{O}$ by reversing all arcs inside of $A$ (i.e., between two vertices in $A$).

**Question**: Suppose that $W$ acts on a finite set $X$. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an acyclic orientation of $G$ and let $A$ be an autonomous subset with respect to $\mathcal{O}$. Set $c := c_{\mathcal{O}}$ and $c' := c_{\mathcal{O}_{-A}}$. Is it true that the orbit structures of $c$ and $c'$ acting on $X$ are the same? In other words, is it true that, viewing the action as a homomorphism $\pi\colon W \to \mathfrak{S}_X$, we have that $\pi(c)$ and $\pi(c')$ are conjugate in $\mathfrak{S}_X$?

Probably it is inessential that $X$ be finite here, but for my purposes that would be enough.

Note that $c$ and $c'$ need not be conjugate in $W$: for example, with $A=G$, then $c'=c^{-1}$, and in general a Coxeter element will not be conjugate to its inverse. But certainly $c$ and $c^{-1}$ have the same orbit structure for any action.

**EDIT**: To make this a little more concrete, let me give one example of one example of an action of $W$ on a finite set.

Let $X$ be the set of independent sets of $G$. Recall that the generators of $W$ are the vertices $v \in G$. For $I\in X$ we define
$$ v\cdot I = \begin{cases} I \cup \{v\} &\textrm{if $v\notin I$ and $I\cup \{v\}$ is an independent set}; \\ I\setminus \{v\} &\textrm{if $v\in I$}; \\ I &\textrm{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
It's easy to check that this gives an action of $W$ on $X$, and in this case I can give an ad hoc argument that $c$ and $c'$ (related by a reversal of an autonomous subset) have the same orbit structure. But I suspect this is a more general phenomenon.

Comment: By the way, is there a name for this property "elements which must become conjugate in any permutation representation"?

Comment: My understanding of your comment is *"what can we say about $g,h$ in a finite group $G$ s.t. for any $n$ and any homomorphism $i:G\to S_n$ we have $i(g)$ and $i(h)$ conjugate?"*. A partial answer is that $\langle g\rangle,\langle h\rangle$ are then conjugate. Indeed, first they have the same order. Then $g$ has a fixed point for the perm. action $i$ on $G/\langle g\rangle$. Since $i(g)$ and $i(h)$ are conjugate, it follows that $h$ has a fixed point, so $\langle h\rangle$ is contained in a conjugate of $\langle g\rangle$. By cardinality this is an equality, so these are conjugate subgroups.

Comment: @YCor: Yes, but in this case $G$ is *not* finite.

Comment: Oops. Still (after reformulating the property without finiteness assumption), my argument only assumes that one of $g,h$ has finite order. And otherwise, it proves that $\langle g\rangle$, $\langle h\rangle$ are contained in conjugates of each other.

Comment: And then the converse holds. Indeed in a (possibly infinite) symmetric group, any two elements generating the same cyclic subgroup are conjugate (since conjugacy classes are only in terms of counting number of cycles of given size). And this is still true for two infinite cyclic subgroups each of which is conjugate to a subgroup of the other one.

Comment: RACGs are known to be conjugacy separable by a theorem of Ferov. Combined with @YCor's nice argument, I think this shows that if two elements are conjugate in every map to a *finite* symmetric group then they must be conjugate. If so, then this answers the question in the negative even for finite actions, since you already noticed that your condition does not imply the two elements are conjugate.

Comment: @HJRW: something must be wrong in what you said, because I know of examples where $c$ and $c^{-1}$ are not conjugate.

Comment: @SamHopkins: that's because YCor's argument only shows that the cyclic subgroups $\langle g\rangle$ and $\langle h\rangle$ are conjugate, not that $g$ and $h$ are conjugate. So I think I'm arguing (tentatively -- my logic may  be incorrect! :)) that if $g$ and $h$ in a RACG are conjugate in every homomorphism to a finite symmetric group, then $g$ should be conjugate to $h^{\pm 1}$. Or at least to a power of $h$, though it's usually the inverse that causes trouble in these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, following the ideas from the comments, I do think there is a counterexample.

Let $G=K_4$, so $W$ is generated by involutions $v_1,\ldots,v_4$ subject to no other relations. Consider the Coxeter element $c=v_1v_2v_3v_4$. We can reverse the autonomous subset $\{v_1,v_2\}$ here to get $c'=v_2v_1v_3v_4$.

Now consider the homomorphism $\phi\colon W\to S_3$ defined by $v_1\mapsto (12)$, $v_2 \mapsto (13)$, $v_3\mapsto (13)$, $v_4\mapsto (23)$. Then $\phi(c)=(12)(13)(13)(23) = (231)$ while $\phi(c') = (13)(12)(13)(23) = e$, so obviously not conjugate.

Clearly what I was thinking could be the case was the wrong thing, but I still believe there should be a broader explanation for this phenomenon of autonomous subset reversal.